# Neo4j how to do a highscore system

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I work in a company that makes a social game where our users can have friends and can make content that based on popularity shows up on highscores.

I am trying to find out whether we can move some of our data to a graph database like neo4j and one of the things I can't figure out is how to implement a highscore system in a graph database. I basically want to make queries like this:
Get list of movies/artbooks/photos content created by friends ordered by content with most likes.

Get list of movies/artbooks/photos content created by ALL USERS in the last 7 days ordered by content with most likes.

What kind of data modeling and queries should we do to implement this?

The datamodel I was planning to do was to have users as nodes and the content made by a user linked to the user as a list of connected content nodes with the latest one linked to the user, but how do I get highscores into such a model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible model:

```
(f:User {name: "Fred"})-[:CREATED]->(c:Content {created: 2345, type: "Music"})

(m:User {name: "Mary"})-[:LIKES {score:5}]->(c:Content)

(f)-[:KNOWS]->(m);
```

To **get the content created by all Users since a specific timestamp, in descending order by the number of likes**, you can use the following query. The `OPTIONAL MATCH` is used to avoid filtering out `Content` with no likes.

```
MATCH (c:Content)
WHERE c.created > 1234
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[l:LIKES]->(c)
RETURN c, COUNT(l) AS num_likes
ORDER BY num_likes DESC;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/sfkipx) that illustrates this.

Comment: you could simply do a `count(l)` instead of `COLLECT` and `LENGTH`